# how to resolve cakephp password reset model validation error

Tags: cakephp, passwords

I've combined a cakephp 2.0 [ACL plugin](http://goo.gl/Jp1iC) with Voidet [SignMeUp plugin](http://goo.gl/vjMa9) to get full user management (ACL, registration, forgotten password). I've got the ACL management and registration from SignMeUp part working. The problem I'm having is with SignMeUp's forgotten password method.

Here is the forgot password view:

```
<h2>Reset Your Password</h2>
<p>Please enter your email address below:</p>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->end('Reset Password');
```

Here is the SignMeUp forgottenpassword component:

```
    public function forgottenPassword() {
    extract($this->settings);
    $model = $this->controller->modelClass;
    if (!empty($this->controller->request->data[$model])) {
        $data = $this->controller->request->data[$model];
    }

    //User has code to reset their password
    if (!empty($this->controller->request->params[$password_reset_field])) {
        $this->__generateNewPassword($model);
    } elseif (!empty($password_reset_field) && !empty($data['email'])) {
        $this->__requestNewPassword($data, $model);
    }
}

private function __generateNewPassword($model = '') {
    extract($this->settings);
    $user = $this->controller->{$model}->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array($password_reset_field => $this->controller->request->params[$password_reset_field]),
        'recursive' => -1
    ));

    if (!empty($user)) {
        $password = substr(Security::hash(String::uuid(), null, true), 0, 8);
        $user[$model][$password_field] = Security::hash($password, null, true);
        $user[$model][$password_reset_field] = null;
        $this->controller->set(compact('password'));
        if ($this->controller->{$model}->save($user) && $this->__sendNewPassword($user[$model])) {
            if (!$this->controller->request->is('ajax')) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Thank you '.$user[$model][$username_field].', your new password has been emailed to you.');
                $this->controller->redirect($this->Auth->loginAction);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

    private function __requestNewPassword($data = array(), $model = '') {
    extract($this->settings);
    $this->controller->loadModel($model);
    $user = $this->controller->{$model}->find('first', array('conditions' => array('email' => $data['email']), 'recursive' => -1));
    if (!empty($user)) {
        $user[$model][$password_reset_field] = md5(String::uuid());

        if ($this->controller->{$model}->save($user) && $this->__sendForgottenPassword($user[$model])) {
            if (!$this->controller->request->is('ajax')) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Thank you. A password recovery email has now been sent to '.$data['email']);
                $this->controller->redirect($this->Auth->loginAction);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->controller->{$model}->invalidate('email', 'No user found with email: '.$data['email']);
    }
}
```

Here is the User model code:

```
    App::uses('AclManagementAppModel', 'AclManagement.Model');
    class User extends AclManagementAppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $useTable = "users";
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'), 'SignMeUp.SignMeUp');
    public $validate = array(
            'name' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'You must enter your real name.'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'required' => false,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'Invalid email.',
                'last' => true
            ),
            'unique' => array(
                'required' => false,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Email already in use.'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => false,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'rule' => 'comparePwd',
            'message' => 'Password mismatch or less than 6 characters.'
        )
    );` 



public function comparePwd($check) {
    $check['password'] = trim($check['password']);

    if (!isset($this->data['User']['id']) && strlen($check['password']) < 6) {
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($this->data['User']['id']) && empty($check['password'])) {
        return true;
    }

    $r = ($check['password'] == $this->data['User']['password2'] && strlen($check['password']) >= 6);

    if (!$r) {
        $this->invalidate('password2', __d('user', 'Password missmatch.'));
    }

    return $r;
}`
```

and here is the error message I get when submitting the form:

Notice (8): Undefined index:  password2 [APP\Plugin\AclManagement\Model\User.php, line 119]

The code related to this message is:

```
$r = ($check['password'] == $this->data['User']['password2'] && strlen($check['password']) >= 6);
```

the context states:

```
$check = array(
'password' => '*****'
```

)

So, what I'm trying to understand is how to deal with this error coming from the user model. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

From this error

> Notice (8): Undefined index: password2 [APP\Plugin\AclManagement\Model\User.php, line 119]

And this error-context:

```
$check = array(
     'password' => '*****'
);
```

The data passed to save is missing the field `password2`.

### Calling save to update the password

It looks like the relevant function is: `__generateNewPassword`. Just ensure that both `password` and `password2` are present with the same value, and it should work:

```
private function __generateNewPassword($model = '') {
    ...

    if (!empty($user)) {
        $password = substr(Security::hash(String::uuid(), null, true), 0, 8);
        $hashedPw = Security::hash($password, null, true);
        $user[$model]['password'] = $hashedPw;
        $user[$model]['password2'] = $hashedPw;
        ...
```

If this is not the save call which is causing the error - check the error stack-trace to see where save is being called from in your case.

Note that the validation function is quite a poor implementation. The password has to be hashed to be stored correctly - the validation logic for "must be more than 6 chars" is applying that rule *to the hashed password* which will always be 40 chars long. Sending out passwords by email is also not the best way to handle password reset logic - it is much better to ask the user to set a new password themselves, instead of sending out a password in plain text by email.

Comment: Thanks AD7six, that was my understanding. However, it's only the email that has an input not password. I think I understand from the component that if the email exists then generate a new password and send it. But when it gets to the model it's trying to compare a password2 that's not there. Does that make sense?

Comment: I doubt that's how it works otherwise just by knowing a user's email you could reset their password. should be: request to reset password -> email sent -> user clicks on link in email -> [password changing process]

Comment: thanks again. I'll work on the hashed passwords as well as an option to send out a ticket instead of a changed password. Will report back.